# Umidigi F1 battery percentage

Tags: battery, notification-bar

I recently bought a Umidigi F1 smartphone, and I can't figure out how to enable battery percentage to always be displayed in the notification bar. If I go to Settings -> Battery there's no option to enable that.

Comment: I don't think stock Android gives that option. Some OEMs provide this option under Settings - > Status bar. You can check there. Otherwise, GravityBox xposed module can do that, but requires a rooted device.

Comment: @Firelord Using a Nokia 8.1 here. Stock Android One device and there's that setting in battery. I believe if its not there then it can be hidden under SystemUI tuner hidden settings. For the rest, I don't think Xposed is available for Android 9, at least not officially.

Comment: Seems that I can't enable the SystemUI tuner. Nothing happens when I press and hold the gear.